# How to handle EntityExistsException properly?

Tags: java, jpa, unique-constraint

I have two entities: Question and FavoritesCounter. FavoritesCounter should be created  when the question is added to favorites for the first time.

Consider a use case when two users tries to add a question to favorites simultaneously - this will cause `EntityExistsException` when `entityManager.persist(counter)` is called for the second user.

But the code below **doesn't work**, because when `EntityExistsException` is thrown, container marks transaction as *rollback only* and attempt to return `getFavoritesCounter(question)` fails with `javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active`

```
@Stateless
public class FavoritesServiceBean implements FavoritesService {

  ...

  public void addToFavorites(Question question) {
    FavoritesCounter counter = getCounter(question);
    if (counter == null) {
      counter = createCounter(question);
    }
    //increase counter
  }

  private FavoritesCounter createCounter(Question question) {
    try {
      FavoritesCounter counter = new FavoritesCounter();
      counter.setQuestion(question);
      entityManager.persist(counter);
      entityManager.flush();
      return counter;
    } catch (EntityExistsException e) {
      return getFavoritesCounter(question);
    }
  }

  private FavoritesCounter getFavoritesCounter(Question question) {
    Query counterQuery = entityManager.createQery("SELECT counter FROM FavoritesCounter counter WHERE counter.question = :question");
    counterQuery.setParameter("question", question);
    List<FavoritesCounter> result = counterQuery.getResultList();
    if (result.isEmpty()) return null;
    return result.get(0);
  }

}
```

**Question**

```
@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  //getter and setter for id

}
```

**FavoritesCounter**

```
@Entity
public class FavoritesCounter implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @Column(unique = true)
  private Question question;

  //getter and setter

}
```

What is the best way to return already created entity after `EntityExistsException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move createCounter() to another Session Bean and mark that method with `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)`

Alternately you can move createCounter() to the local interface of FavoritesServiceBean (also ensuring you add the `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)` annotation) and call it as follows:

```
@Stateless
public class FavoritesServiceBean implements FavoritesService 
{

    ...
    @Resource
    protected SessionContext sessionContext;

    public void addToFavorites(Question question) 
    {
        FavoritesCounter counter = getCounter(question);
        if (counter == null) {
          counter = sessionContext.getBusinessObject(FavoritesService.class)
                                  .createCounter(question);
        }
       //increase counter
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
    public FavoritesCounter createCounter(Question question) 
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

You need to go through the business/local interface rather calling createCounter() directly so the container knows to start a new transaction.